# File type associations on OS X for Citrix Online Plugin

Tags: macos, file-association, iphoto, citrix, citrix-receiver

I would like to associate .ICA files with Citrix online plugin, which is positioned at `/Library/Application\ Support/Citrix/Citrix\ online\ plug-in.app/Citrix.app`.

How to do it?

The problem is, in the "Open with" menu I can select only apps in `/Application` folder!

(NOTE: unfortunately OS X thinks .ICA files belongs to iPhoto, which is not my case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm running Mtn Lion and can navigate to any folder in the Open With dialog box--you need to hit the button at the top, to the left of the search box.  You can then navigate to your HD->Library folder.  Once you select the citrix app, be sure to check Always Open With (near the bottom)

Alternate method: select any ica file, hit command-i, find the Open With section, navigate to the Citrix app, then click Change All.

Comment: You are absolutely right: I must have been drunk when I tried to do it! ;)